# adding values to an array of int's array's and saving it to .plist file

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to save an array with 12 arrays of int values array to a .plist file. [[NSNumber]]

In each call of a delegate method I get a same array and I need to add it to the already saved values in it .. 80 int values to each array in the 12 size array .

The thing is that it adds the same values to each array and it ends up as 12 arrays with the same values .

What am I doing wrong ?

```
var array:[NSMutableArray] = [NSMutableArray](repeating: [], count: 12)

func dataReceived(withData data: [[NSNumber]]!) {

    for i in 0..<12 {
            (array[i] as AnyObject).addObjects(from: data[i])
            }
        }

}
```

This method is called after the scan ends .

```
 func completed(_ with:Bool){
        if(with){
            
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
            let path = documentDirectory.appending("/\(Int.random(in: 1..<5000)).plist")
            if (!fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)) {
                let success = (array as NSArray).write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
                if success {
                    print("file has been created!")
                }else{
                    print("unable to create the file")
                }
                
            }else{
                print("file already exist")
            }
        }
    }
```

A .plist file is created with a 12 items array that contains the same values .

Comment: Why are you working with old NS classes instead of native types line `Array`?

Comment: I converted the code from objc. I work with an objc sdk

Comment: @ndrzhr In that case I would code a thin layer that translates all Objective-C/Foundation types that are coming from the sdk to Swift types  (NSMutableArray to array, NSNumber to Int/Double/Float, etc) before using any of it. This would lead to code that is clearer and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong with your objective-c-ish code but the below code should work the way you want it

```
var array: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: [], count: 12)

func dataReceived(with data: [[Int]]) {
    guard data.count == 12 else { return }

    for (index, values) in data.enumerated() {
        array[index].append(contentsOf: values)
    }
}
```

Comment: Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'append'.

Comment: Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'append'.
since there is another func that uses the data as a [[NSnumber]] I can't change it to Int.

Comment: @ndrzhr The code above also works with NSNumber

Comment: Changing the [NSMutableArray] to [Array]Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift.__EmptyArrayStorage addObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fa17a0d0'     var array:[NSMutableArray] = [NSMutableArray](repeating: [], count: 12) >>var array:[Array] = [Array](repeating: [], count: 12)

Comment: var array: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: [], count: 12)
    func dataReceived(withData data: [[NSNumber]]!) {
        
        guard data.count == 12 else { return }

           for (index, values) in data.enumerated() {
               array[index].append(contentsOf: values)
           } 
} >>  No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239309/discussion-between-ndrzhr-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: @ndrzhr did this answer help?